# How to hide json field when using Springdata pageable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, mybatis

Currently I'm using SpringData to build my restful project.

I'm using  Page findAll(Pageable pageable, X condition, String... columns); ,this method .The result looks like this:

{

```
"content": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "ouId": 1,
        "pClassId": 3,
        "isPublic": 0,
        "accessMethod": 3,
        "modifierName": null
    }
],
"last": true,
"totalPages": 1,
"totalElements": 3,
"number": 0,
"size": 10,
"sort": [
    {
        "direction": "DESC",
        "property": "id",
        "ignoreCase": false,
        "nullHandling": "NATIVE",
        "ascending": false,
        "descending": true
    }
],
"first": true,
"numberOfElements": 3
```

}

The question is how to hide some specific json field in the content ?
And @JsonIgnore annotation is not flexible ， the fields I need in different APIs are different.

I tried to write an annotation ,but when processing the Page ,I found that the content is unmodifiable .

So , hope that someone could help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to put annotations on your Pojos you can also use [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/).

Here is how you can exclude a field with it without any annotations (you can also use annotations if you want, but you have the choice).

```
Genson genson = new Genson.Builder().exclude("securityCode", User.class).create();
// and then
String json = genson.serialize(user);
```

OR using flexjson

```
import flexjson.JSONDeserializer;
import flexjson.JSONSerializer;
import flexjson.transformer.DateTransformer;

public String toJson(User entity) {
        return new JSONSerializer().transform(new DateTransformer("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), java.util.Date.class)
       .include("wantedField1","wantedField2")
                .exclude("unwantedField1").serialize(entity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a custom serialize like the following:

```
@JsonComponent
public class MovieSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Movie> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Movie movie, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {

        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();

        // The basic information of a movie
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("id", movie.getId());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("name", movie.getName());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("poster", movie.getPoster());
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField("releaseDate", movie.getReleaseDate());
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField("runtime", movie.getRuntime());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("storyline", movie.getStoryline());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("rated", movie.getRated());
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("rating", movie.getRating());
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

And then annotate your model class with:  `@JsonSerialize(using = MovieSerializer.class)`